# Algorithm: find friends from a list of users

Tags: algorithm

Scenario: in my app, users could follow a post. They will get notified whenever their friends liked the post. The problem gets nontrivial when there are thousands of users following and like a post.

My current approach is simply, when a new user likes a post, iterate through all the users who have followed the post, and check whether the new user exists in their friend list (let's say the average size is `N`). I indexed the friend list, so the look up is `O(logN)`, which means for each new like, the computation is `O(klogN)` if there are `k` people following the post and directly since there are k users who like it, then the overall complexity becomes `O(k^2logN)`. Can I do better than this?

Note:

1. Notification does not have to be instant, nor does it have to happen 100% of the times
2. Posts are created by users
3. I am using Firestore, a NoSQL database, if that matters

Comment: Would it be easier in this case if you iterate through new user's friend list and find those who followed this post and notify them?

Comment: @adev actually it quite depends on the OP's design, it can become worse if the `checking` you mentioned becomes linear instead of logarithmic as before since followers are always far less than the amount of the average friend list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think it can be improved to `N^2 + k logN^2` by using more memory space. This problem is fundamentally that of finding intersection of two sets (the set of friends of the new liked user and the set of followers, OR the set of friends of the followers and the the set of liked users). Since look up is cheap, we want to make the set to be looked up be as big as possible. So if we put all the friends of all the followers into one big set (more specifically a map) of size `N^2`, it becomes `k logN^2` if there are k liked users, plus initial iteration of `N^2`

Additional benefit of aggregating friends together is that many users have mutual friends, so actual size may be smaller than `N^2`

Answer (score 0):

What you need to use is a hybrid approach. Take advantage of the fact that the users friend list might be shorter than the number of followers, or vice versa. There are two options:

- Do what you do now, and check **every follower** against the new user's **friends list**. The time complexity reflects the number of followers.
- Do the reverse, and check **every friend** of the user against the **followers list** for the post. The time complexity reflects the number of friends of the user.

Armed with these tactics, now we design an algorithm to check which of the two will give the better performance.

Keep an active count of the number of friends of each user, and of the followers of a post. When someone likes a post, if they have fewer friends than there are people that liked the post, its faster to check if each friend is in the followers list (use a self-balancing BST or hash table in the implementation). If there are fewer followers than the user has friends, the reverse would be faster.

If there are N followers, K users liking the post, and F friends, the checking friend->follower would give a run time of `O(N*F*log(K))`, and follower->friend would be `O(N*K*log(F))`. The worst case still remains the same, however if you were only concerned about theoretical time bounds then you could substitute your index table with a hash table anyways which is `O(1)` instead of `O(log(n))` anyways.